# expire application after 1 year span from client PC, No internet is available on client PC

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, desktop-application

I have one vb.net windows application and I want to deliver it to my client with 1 year validity.

After one year this software will automatically stop working or ask for renewal.

The client PC doesn't have internet access.
Please tell me the secure way for this.

Comment: "the secure way for this." Good luck. Nothing will be foolproof and a good cracker/hacker can easily circumvent this security. Your best bet is to hide the start date, last opened date, and last closed date in multiple places (registry, encrypted files, bits in a JPEG, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the program is installed, have it set a registry value with the current date. Then, on every subsequent program start, have it check that registry value against the current time. If more than a year has passed, do whatever you plan on doing to lock up your application.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b22e94c-37a9-4be5-ad55-3d9229220194/how-to-use-add-read-change-delete-registry-keys-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral) has some excellent info on the specifics of adding, modifying, and accessing registry values in `vb.net`.

Comment: To avoid the user from changing the date to get around this. Store the last opened date. When the user opens this again, compare with the current date and the last opened date. If the opened date is before the last opened date. The date has been tampered with, then you can put in a message and quit

Answer (score 1):

Check the date.

```
If dateToday > dateProgramSold.AddYears(1) Then 
   'open form that cant be close saying program is expired
End If
```

Comment: You could check the date on a server or another computer if the computer is connected to a lan. Other than that yes the user could manually change the date on his/her computer.

Answer (score 0):

When the program is installed, it should ask for an registration key (they could get it by email, print it off and type it). The key should contain the last day of validity (encrypted). Store the key in the registry (or somewhere else). When the program starts, you check the date inside the key.

If they re-install the end date will stay the same.

When they want to update, just send a new key by email or mail.

The amount of security you put into just could depend on how much you trust the company. Because they could always decompile and crack your software.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for a program I wrote. My final solution included the resolution that you can't be 100% foolproof, so I considered my users and did the best I could with what I had.

Without access to the internet, how does the computer know what date it is? It has to rely on user input for it. So if a user can input it, then a user can change it. There is no foolproof way to get an accurate date from the PC without the the user having access to it. Whether from the OS, the BIOS, etc.

So what I ended up doing was putting an obfuscated key into the registry in an obscure place. HKCU >> Software. I made the key just some letters and numbers {L12A3C0DFF} then I named the key Z0B0 and made the value the obfuscated date. I took the year month and day and ran each one through a different calculation. I ended up with something that looked like DDE011468932.

Each time the program ran it decoded this registry setting to see if a year had passed based on the time in the BIOS. If the date in the BIOS was earlier then this date then they changed it and I would not not allow my program to run.

Also each time the program ran, I checked the date in the BIOS and stored this in the registry in the same way. So I would check to see if they changed the date in the BIOS to an earlier date.

So in order for them to abuse the date restriction of one year, they literally had to change the date in the BIOS every day which I figured was not worth it to them to do, besides, they would have had to figure out where I was getting the date from to begin with, which would take decompiling (and I wasn't selling it to a bunch of programmers). Simply changing the date in the OS wouldn't fool it.

Comment: i will try..nice concept